# php imageresolution

Tags: php, gd

В php есть функция *http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imageresolution.php*
Запускал ее на разных хостингах с php 7+.

В итоге:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imageresolution()........

Остальные функции GD работают нормально.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Именно (PHP 7 >= 7.2.0)?

Comment: 7+ но видимо 7.2-

Comment: Не думаю, что на популярных хостингах уже внедрили 7.2 Поэтому и ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. Данная функция реализована только начиная с версии php 7.2

> imageresolution
>
> **(PHP 7 >= 7.2.0)**
>
> imageresolution — Get or set the resolution of the image
>
> http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imageresolution.php